# How does you create an LSTM layer in CNTK, from C++?

Tags: cntk

CNTK generally provides a great C++ API, but I'm struggling to find out how to build LSTM or GRU layers from the C++ API. The only function I can find is `OptimizedRNNStack`. That function seems quite self-explanatory, except for the `weights` variable. So far I haven't managed to figure out how to initialize that `weights` variable. Looking at `CNTK.core.bs`, it seems to initialize the weights with:

```
ParameterTensor {0:0, initFilterRank=0, initOutputRank=-1, init=init, 
initValueScale=initValueScale}`
```

but I can't figure out how to translate that into C++. For context - I'm trying to use CTC to build an OCR pipeline. Building everything in C++ is great, because I can use all the native data synthesis tools, and the entire pipeline can be trained and tested end-to-end. However, if I must build the model in Brainscript, I guess that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ API does not have a Layers library equivalent. I have struggled to do that as the static-typing nature of C++ makes it hard to support all those options. Let me share a private piece of C++ code that creates a GRU simimilar to the Layers library (without all the options).

Sorry this is not directly copy-pastable; please try to change the return value to Function, and change the lambda signature by creating two PlaceholderVariables, dh, and x. That funny `let` is short for `const auto`.

```
static BinaryModel GRU(size_t outputDim, const DeviceDescriptor& device)
{
    let activation = [](const Variable& x) { return Tanh(x); };
    auto W  = Parameter({ outputDim * 3, NDShape::InferredDimension }, DataType::Float, GlorotUniformInitializer(), device, L"W");
    auto R  = Parameter({ outputDim * 2, outputDim }, DataType::Float, GlorotUniformInitializer(), device, L"R");
    auto R1 = Parameter({ outputDim    , outputDim }, DataType::Float, GlorotUniformInitializer(), device, L"R1");
    auto b  = Parameter({ outputDim * 3 }, 0.0f, device, L"b");
    let stackAxis = vector<Axis>{ Axis(0) };
    let stackedDim = (int)outputDim;
    let one = Constant::Scalar(1.0f, device); // for "1 -"...
    // e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit
    return BinaryModel({ W, R, R1, b }, [=](const Variable& dh, const Variable& x)
    {
        let& dhs = dh;
        // projected contribution from input(s), hidden, and bias
        let projx3 = b + Times(W, x);
        let projh2 = Times(R, dh);
        let zt_proj = Slice(projx3, stackAxis, 0 * stackedDim, 1 * stackedDim) + Slice(projh2, stackAxis, 0 * stackedDim, 1 * stackedDim);
        let rt_proj = Slice(projx3, stackAxis, 1 * stackedDim, 2 * stackedDim) + Slice(projh2, stackAxis, 1 * stackedDim, 2 * stackedDim);
        let ct_proj = Slice(projx3, stackAxis, 2 * stackedDim, 3 * stackedDim);

        let zt = Sigmoid(zt_proj)->Output();        // fun update gate z(t)

        let rt = Sigmoid(rt_proj);                  // reset gate r(t)

        let rs = dhs * rt;                          // "cell" c
        let ct = activation(ct_proj + Times(R1, rs));

        let ht = (one - zt) * ct + zt * dhs; // hidden state ht / output

        return ht;
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that the Slice() function requires to pass all 3 args as vectors, like vector<int>{ 0 * stackeDim }. I recommend to write a small wrapper function static Slice(const Variable&, const Axis&, int, int).